# PowerBI Blank Data Issue

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, slicers

I'm pulling the data with sql and I've checked many times, there is no problem in my relationships. the main problem is: As seen in the image, the slicer also shows empty data, but there is no empty data in my database.

[image]

also when ı add numeric data to charts only blank data appears

[image]

Under normal circumstances, the stacked column chart would show the X axis as empty. However, when I activate the 'show items with no data' option, other fields are also displayed, but only blank data is shown, but there is no blank data.

[image]

There were empty values ​​from the database in the ProductSubcategoryKey,Color,ModelName fields, and I replaced these values ​​with replace value. But even though I change and filter, the blank values ​​keep coming.

Comment: Can you share your pbix